# como puede python consultar un fichero .txt si no tiene el servicio instalado tras su revision

Tags: python

Actualmente tengo un bot que funciona con Slack, cuando tu le solicitas un archivo, el bot te lo envia.
Lo que hace para saber si tiene el archivo es consultar si tiene un servicio instalado.
Si lo tiene lo manda, si no lo tiene se calla y no responde.
Necesitaría saber como puedo configurarlo para que cuando no tenga ese servicio instalado, consulte directamente un archivo.txt.

Si no tiene el servicio en ese archivo txt responderá indicando que no tiene ese servicio.
El archivo txt se encuentra en una carpeta en la que para poder abrirlo tienes que poner usuario y contraseña.

El código del bot es el siguiente:

```
    def enviarcopia(self, instalacion):

    #Comprobar si servicio esta y tiene valor
    service = None
    try:
        name = "servicioxxxx"
        service = psutil.win_service_get(name)
        service = service.as_dict()         
        #ejecutar comando de envio de copia
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(service))
    if service:
        print "service found"
        subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Utils\scripts\HacerCopiaYEnviarACopiasNetconpython.bat', instalacion])  
        return "servicio encontrado"
        time.sleep(60) # espera en segundos
        
        #si no lo encuentra
    else:
        print("error")

        return ""
```

Me gustaria lo que he indicado para que si no tiene el servicio instalado consulte un archivo.txt en la que para poder acceder a ese archivo se necesita usuario y contraseña.

El codigo siguiente habría que modificarlo para que consulte el fichero.

```
            #si no lo encuentra
    else:
        print("error")

        return ""
```

Disculpar mi ignorancia en python pero voy haciendo las cosas gracias a google.

Estoy intentando hacer esto pero tampoco me sirve

```
    #Comprobar si servicio esta y tiene valor
    service = None
    try:
        name = "servicioxxxx"
        service = psutil.win_service_get(name)
        service = service.as_dict()         
        #ejecutar comando de envio de copia
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(service))
    if service:
        print "service found"
        subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Utils\scripts\HacerCopiaYEnviarACopiasNetconpython.bat', instalacion])  
        return "servicio encontrado"
        time.sleep(60) # espera en segundos
        
        #si no 
    else:
#buscar fichero     
        fichero = open('C:\Prueba bat\ejemplo.txt')
        try:
        # Usar el fichero
            pass
        finally:
            fichero.close()
        return ""
```

Parece ser que aun así el bot responde como none como que no va a responder

Comment: Ahi se entiendo mucho mejor.

Comment: Genial, y sabrias que es lo que peudo hacer?